# How to use remote interpreter with jupyter notebook on pycharm 2018.1

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

In official documentation, it is explained how to use remote interpreter for jupyter notebook on pycharm 2018.1.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/ipython-notebook-support.html

It's said to choose Remote radio-button, which is not present there, and event not in the screenshot in the documentation itself.

Am I missing smth?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation seems to be outdated, I created a ticket to fix it [PY-29289](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29289).

Remote notebook support requires clarification: PyCharm doesn't support running notebooks with remote interpreters: [PY-26328](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26328). But it supports a connection to Jupyter notebook or Jupyterhub server running on the remote machine: [PY-14605](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14605). The latter requires:

- a running [notebook server](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html) or [jupyterhub](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on the remote machine
- correct credentials setup as covered by the existed documentation

Remote interpreter, in this case, is only required for a proper code highlighting and inspections. Theoretically one can skip it completely.

Current documentation lacks a good complete setup guide, I created an internal ticket for documentation team to rewrite the corresponding page. Meanwhile, I found the [notebook server documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html) to be a good step-by-step reference for remote machine configuration if you are interested in this approach.