# Running jupyter notebook remotely from PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to run jupyter notebook remotely. I set python remote interpreter, host, port and everything. I even made a successful connection to jupyter notebook server with token. The problem is when I run a cell (print Hello world). There is a * mark but I'm not sure if it's even running or not. Also I attached the screenshot of my jupyter notebook configuration and there is an error "Please select local python interpreter".

Does anybody here have the same problem?

I'm using trial version of pycharm build #PY-181.4203.547 on macOS 10.13.3.

[image: pycharm keeps asking for local interpreter]

Comment: Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589305/2787185

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating running Jupyter notebook server not on localhost, but on public IP 0.0.0.0 and port 5000.

Server config:

[image: Server Config]

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///run/user/1001/jupyter/nbserver-18243-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://111.11.11.111:5000/?token=ab6f22d9176774b8dccb08cc87414fe8a64bb58e6cc10910 [I 02:28:19.329 NotebookApp] 302 GET / (69.140.134.16) 0.76ms [I 02:28:19.403 NotebookApp] 302 GET /tree? (69.140.134.16) 0.74ms [I 02:28:19.609 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 306aaa82-b824-4fd0-8b8f-dd35271f79ef [W 02:28:19.689 NotebookApp] No session ID specified [I 02:28:20.122 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 306aaa82-b824-4fd0-8b8f-dd35271f79ef
```